# Determinant of an $n \times n$-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can you help me with this $n\times  n$ determinant? Can't find what from what i have to substract.. Spent hours of trying...

\begin{vmatrix}
    1&\cdots& 1&  1& 4\\
    1 &\cdots&1 & 9& 1 \\
    1 & \cdots &16& 1 &1\\ 
\vdots & \dots& \vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\    
    (n+1)^2 &\cdots& 1& 1& 1 
    \end{vmatrix}

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You should give an account of what you tried in "hours of trying" and what you discovered.  It will help Readers respond in a helpful way, and in the future make your question a more valuable post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite this matrix as
$$
\pmatrix{0& \cdots & 0 & 0 & 2^2 - 1\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 3^2 - 1 & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 4^2 - 1 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
(n+1)^2 - 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0} + xx^T
$$
where $x = (1,1,\dots,1)^T$.  From there, it suffices to apply the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: Thank you for helping me!